# I'm getting the error "Another exception was thrown: You are trying to use contextless navigation without" when I run my app

Tags: flutter, build

Here is my code

```
              Spacer(), // 1/6
              InkWell(
                onTap: () => Get.to(QuizScreen()),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding * 0.75), // 15
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: kPrimaryGradient,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "Lets Start Quiz",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .button
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Spacer(flex: 2), // it will take 2/6 spaces
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Please can someoene please help me check for the cause of this r=error. I get the error when I tap the button. The project builds fine but i dont get a feedback when i tap the button

Error:  Another exception was thrown: You are trying to use contextless navigation without.

Comment: I have the same error, Have you got a solution for that issue?

Answer (score 14):

You Need to Add `GetMaterialApp` In Your Main.dart file for GetX .

Thanks . Here is the Demo :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getxpro/view/cartPage.dart';
import 'package:getxpro/view/home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp( //for navigation dont forget to use GetMaterialApp
      title: 'getXpro',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/cart': (context) => CartPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: after upgrade to flutter 3 , the error have come again within alr define GetMaterialApp, did u know why ?

Answer (score 1):

first wrap the the widget  with widget where u want to give onclick and turn it into GestureDetector

just to do GetMaterialApp in main.dart

```
GestureDetector(
onTap():{
Get.to(()=>PageName_tobecalled());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).